# Unusual jump condition for Green function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This question is related to a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383750/second-order-nonlinear-ode-with-dirac-delta) I posted a while ago.

Imagine that I'm computing the Green function of a linear operator $L$, such that:
$$LG(x,s)=\delta(x-s).~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$

Now, according to the answer to my previous (indicated) question, I'll have to solve the equation
$$LG(x,s)=0,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2)$$
for $x>s$ and $~x<s$, and find, the usually called, jump condition at $x=s$.

Now, more concretely. If my jump condition is:
$$\lim_{x\to s^+}\log(G(x,s))-\lim_{x\to s^-}\log(G(x,s))=\frac{1}{G(s)},$$
and the function $G$ has the same one-sided limits, the above equation would be $1/G(s)=0$... So, I can't take much information out, right?
So, how does one continue...Or is there something I'm doing wrong?